# PHP to query YouTube URL for thumbnail throws warning on parse_str()

Tags: php, wordpress

I am not sure how to reconcile the following PHP warning:

> Deprecated: parse_str(): Calling parse_str() without the result argument is deprecated

Here's the code which is used as part of a larger snippet to pull the thumbnail from YouTube:

```
if(($parse['host'] == 'youtube.com') || ($parse['host'] == 'www.youtube.com')){
    $video_type = 'youtube';
    parse_str($parse['query']);
    $video_id = $v;
    if(!empty($feature))
        $video_id = end(explode('v=', $parse['query']));
    if(strpos($parse['path'], 'embed') == 1)
        $video_id = end(explode('/', $parse['path']));
}
```

Comment: First it a warning not an error! But to solve it, you look at the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) for the function reported. You notice the difference between your code and the suggested code.

Comment: In the manual page you will see this information: `V7.2.0 Usage of parse_str() without a second parameter now emits an E_DEPRECATED notice.` and `V8.0.0 result is no longer optional.`

Comment: Yes, I see that but I am unsure how to properly include the second parameter and use it throughout the rest of the code provided.

Comment: So setting randon local variables without knowing their names is **V.Dangerous** as you have no idea if you are going to overwrite a variable that already exists and loose something important, or worse still corrupt it or allow a hacker to try setting it to something thay want it to be.

Comment: Give it a second parameter, it will be an array and filled for you. Then work out which local vars you have to change to use variables in the result array

Comment: Run `$result = []; parse_str($parse['query'], $result);` then do a simple `print_r($result);` to see whats in there. Then go looking for code that uses scalar variables with those names and change them to use the `$result` array versions

Comment: OK I think I got it, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing this:

```
parse_str($parse['query']);
$video_id = $v;
```

To this:

```
parse_str($parse['query'], $output);
$video_id = $output['v'];
```

... removed the warning.